# How to extend log4j2 RollingFileAppender?

Tags: java, log4j2, rollingfileappender

I need to copy the gz file after the gzip was done. What is the best way to do this?

1. There is a way to extend the RollingFileAppender?
2. Create another appender - but this means that every log line he will perform this task.
3. Some other way that I don't know of.

Answer (score 3):

You could specify the target folder of the gz file in the `filePattern` attribute of the RollingFile configuration. Maybe I'm oversimplifying but I should mention the simple option first.

An alternative is to create a custom plugin action that runs after the rollover. For inspiration look at the source for [DeleteAction](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/blob/master/log4j-core/src/main/java/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/action/DeleteAction.java).

You can configure your plugin similar to [how the built-in delete action is configured](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/appenders.html#CustomDeleteOnRollover).

Comment: I want to send email along with RollingFile event. Will a custom plugin action work in this case?

Comment: I will raise this to the mailing list

Comment: @Gaurav Was there a reply on the mailing list?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot extend in in log4j2, because apache have made it a final class in log4j2.
In earlier version of log4j you could have easily extended and called the custom class by configuring the appender in the properties file(xml).
Their migration steps also doesn't specify how to move this functionality to log4j2.

Comment: While the class cannot be extended the functionality can by using custom actions. See Remko's answer above for the correct response to this question.